# Is a long stay Hungarian visa valid in all of Schengen?

Tags: schengen, eu, long-stay-visas

I will be working in Hungary from January. The process for work/residence permit and visa application is on and documents are being prepared by the company I will be working with.

Is the Visa same as schengen short term visa ? Will I be able to visit other schengen countries ?

Comment: Is your visa a "D" type visa?

Comment: Although the OP should specify the type of visa in his question, it is mentioned in the title that it is a long-stay visa, therefore, it has to be a type "D" visa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will be free to travel in the Schengen Area using your national "D" type visa.

Legal basis:

**Regulation EU No 265/2010 of the European Parliament and of the Council amending
the Convention Implementing the Schengen Agreement and Regulation (EC) No
562/2006 as regards movement of persons with a long-stay visa**

> The Regulation enters into force on 5 April 2010, which means that
>   from that date  All valid long-stay visas will allow for free
>   circulation in the Schengen area for three months in a six
>   month-period. A third-country national holding a long-stay D visa
>   issued by a Member State will be allowed to travel to the other Member
>   States for three months in any half year, under the same conditions as
>   the holder of a residence permit. In accordance with the Regulation,
>   this rule also applies to long-stay visas already issued before 5
>   April 2010, including still valid D+C visas;

and from the Regulation itself (the Regulation amends **Convention Implementing the Schengen Agreement**, therefore Article references apply to the Convention):

**Article 21:**

> ‘1. Aliens who hold valid residence permits issued by one of the
>   Member States may, on the basis of that permit and a valid travel
>   document, move freely for up to three months in any six-month period
>   within the territories of the other Member States, provided that they
>   fulfil the entry conditions referred to in Article 5(1)(a), (c) and
>   (e) of Regulation (EC) No 562/2006 of the European Parliament and of
>   the Council of 15 March 2006 establishing a Community Code on the
>   rules governing the movement of persons across borders (Schengen
>   Borders Code) (*) and are not on the national list of alerts of the
>   Member State concerned.
>
> [...]
>
> 2a. The right of free movement laid down in paragraph 1 shall also apply
>   to aliens who hold a valid long-stay visa issued by one of the Member
>   States as provided for in Article 18.’.

**Article 18:**

> 1. Visas for stays exceeding three months (long-stay visas) shall be national visas issued by one of the Member States in accordance with
>      its national law or Union law. Such visas shall be issued in the
>      uniform format for visas as set out in Council Regulation (EC) No
>      1683/95 (*) with the heading specifying the type of visa with the
>      letter “D”. They shall be filled out in accordance with the relevant
>      provisions of Annex VII to Regulation (EC) No 810/2009 of the European
>      Parliament and of the Council of 13 July 2009 establishing a Community
>      Code on Visas (Visa Code) (**).

**Source:**

1. http://www.sztokholm.msz.gov.pl/resource/22c47820-a6ec-4d81-9601-a7211e2316c4:JCR (information note from Polish Embassy in Stockholm)
2. http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2010:085:0001:0004:EN:PDF

Comment: Doesn't the 90/180 rule apply to "D" visa holders in the rest of the schengen area?

Comment: It does, as mentioned in the information note I linked: `All valid long-stay visas will allow for free circulation in the Schengen area for three months in a six month-period. `.  I will add proper sections from the Regulation itself.

Comment: (+1) The conclusion is essentially correct, but you should use the consolidated version of the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32016R0399) rather than the regulations amending it or the convention itself. The current rule (for almost all nationalities) is 90 days in any 180-day period (cf. article 6 of the Borders code) rather than three months in any six-month period anymore.

Comment: @EdmundDantes sorry to ping you here but why did you delete your answer on the Poland/Canadian citizen question? It looked fine for me save for that you would need to correct that one can be asked to present ID by police. Consider un-deleting and editing and feel free to use the links I posted as a comment to the question if you find them useful. Also if you ping me I will +1.

Comment: @mts, I got angry at my answer, after I read it again, and I didn't want to edit it, as it was too long :)